# Vuejs Old Value in Select Option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to keep and show old data of select elements in Vuejs?

My code is like below

```
 <select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>

  export default {

  data() {
    return {
      selected: "A",
      options: [
        { text: "One", value: "A" },
        { text: "Two", value: "B" },
        { text: "Three", value: "C" }
      ],
}}}
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you please specify the real issue?

Comment: Is this about keeping the selected value after switching the component and come back?

Comment: Yes, Mr. Rijosh keeping the selected value after switching the component and come back

Comment: You can either use `store` to bind the `v-model` or wrap your component with `<keep-alive>` tag.

Comment: I have a profile form that has security questions in the dropdown list, users select the questions and then provide answers. I only store the security answers in the database What I want is when the user comes to his profile page the  security questions in the dropdown list that he has chosen should be in the dropdown  as selected

Comment: Are you using `vue-router` for switching components?

Comment: yes but I put the  <li> <router-link to="/Supplier" class="nav-link" onclick="location.reload();" >پلورونکي </router-link></li>  which refresh the page

Comment: This solution won't work if you're refreshing the page. In this case you can try using the browser localStorage or database instead.

Comment: I don't want to use database, How I can use the browser localStorage

Comment: You can set the value into browser localStorage using  `localStorage.setItem('selected',your_value)` I'll add detailed solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution 1:* Use `keep alive`

```
<keep-alive>
  <your-component>
</keep-alive>
```

This will keep your component data alive and show even you switch the component.

*Solution 2:* Using `store` to bind the data

Inside your `state`

```
const state = {
  selected: "A"
}
```

In the mutations

```
const mutations = {
  SET_SELECTED:(state,value)=>state.selected = value
}
```

Now in your component add a `computed` function (you can remove the `selected` from the `data`)

```
selected: {
  get: function () {
    return this.$store.state.selected;
  },
  set: function (value) {
    this.$store.commit('SET_SELECTED', value);
  }
}
```

### Solution using `localStorage`

> state

```
const state = {
  selected: localStorage.getItem('selected') || null
}
```

> mutations

```
const mutations = {
  SET_SELECTED:(state,value)=>{
    state.selected = value;
    localStorage.setItem('selected',value);
  }
}
```